# Parent component is connected to redux store, but Child component isn't re-rending on state change

Tags: reactjs, redux

When I change the data for a budget object in my redux store the components that are responsible for rendering that object aren't re-rendering the component when the data is changed.

I have a `<Budget />` component that renders a budget object contained in an array of budget objects that are part of my state/store. My store has the following shape:

```
departmentBudgets  : {
    isFetching : false,
    budgets    : [ {
        department : 'String',
        owner      : {
            name  : 'String',
            email : 'String',
            title : 'String'
        },
        budget     : 'Number'
    } ]
}
```

I would like the `<Budget />` component to re-render and update the display of the budget object when one of its properties are edited. The functionality I'm working on is allowing the user to edit and update the budget property. My redux reducer looks like the following:

```
import * as types from '../constants/actionTypes';
import union from 'lodash/array/union';
import uniq from 'lodash/array/uniq';

const initialState = {
    isFetching : false,
    budgets    : []
};

export default function budgets( state = initialState, action = {} ) {
    const { type, payload, meta } = action;

    switch ( type ) {
        case types.FETCH_CURRENT_BUDGETS:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isFetching : true
            });
        case types.RECEIVE_CURRENT_BUDGETS:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isFetching : false,
                budgets    : uniq(union(state.budgets, payload), '_id')
            });
        case types.UPDATE_DEPARTMENT_BUDGET:
            const changedIndex = state.budgets.findIndex(( budget ) => {
                return budget._id === payload._id;
            });
            const newBudgets = [ ...state.budgets.slice(0, changedIndex),
                Object.assign({}, state.budgets[ changedIndex ], {
                    budget : payload.budget
                }),
                ...state.budgets.slice(changedIndex + 1) ];
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                budgets : newBudgets
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Am I handling the update correctly in the reducer above? I believe that this isn't mutating the state object, but maybe not?

My react component tree looks like the following to render this data:

```
DepartmentBudgetsContainer
  DepartmentBudgets
    Budget
```

The container element grabs the current data from the database and connects it to the store with react-redux and looks like the following:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchBudgets, updateBudget } from '../../actions/departmentBudget.actions';
import DepartmentBudgets from '../../components/administration/department_budgets/DepartmentBudgets';

const displayName = 'DepartmentBudgetContainer';
const propTypes = {
    budgets : PropTypes.object
};

class DepartmentBudgetContainer extends Component {
    constructor( props, context ) {
        super(props, context);
        this.budgetDidchange = this.budgetDidchange.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let { dispatch } = this.props;
        dispatch(fetchBudgets());
    }

    budgetDidchange( id, budget ) {
        let { dispatch } = this.props;
        const newBudget = {
            _id    : id,
            budget : budget
        };
        dispatch(updateBudget(newBudget));
    }

    render() {
        const { budgets } = this.props;
        return (
            <DepartmentBudgets updateBudget={this.budgetDidchange} budgets={budgets.budgets} />
        );
    }
}

DepartmentBudgetContainer.displayName = displayName;
DepartmentBudgetContainer.propTypes = propTypes;

function mapStateToProps( state ) {
    return {
        budgets : state.departmentBudgets.budgets
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DepartmentBudgetContainer);
```

And then the DepartmentBudgets component is responsible for creating each of the Budget components and looks like the following:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import TableComps from '../../../../node_modules/material-ui/lib/table';
import Budget from './Budget';

const Table = TableComps.Table;
const TableHeader = TableComps.TableHeader;
const TableRow = TableComps.TableRow;
const TableHeaderColumn = TableComps.TableHeaderColumn;
const TableBody = TableComps.TableBody;
const TableRowColumn = TableComps.TableRowColumn;

const displayName = 'DepartmentBudgets';
const propTypes = {
    budgets      : PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
    updateBudget : PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default class DepartmentBudgets extends Component {
    constructor( props ) {
        super(props);     
    }

    render() {
        const { budgets, updateBudget } = this.props;

        const budgetsElements = budgets.map(( budget ) => {
            return <Budget updateBudget={updateBudget} key={budget._id} budget={budget} />
        });

        return (
            <Table>
                <TableHeader adjustForCheckbox={false}
                             displaySelectAll={false}>
                    <TableRow onCellClick={this.handleCellClick}>
                        <TableHeaderColumn>Department</TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn>Budget</TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn>Owner</TableHeaderColumn>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHeader>
                <TableBody stripedRows={false}>
                    {budgetsElements}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        );
    }
}

DepartmentBudgets.displayName = displayName;
DepartmentBudgets.propTypes = propTypes;
```

Finally, the Budget component is responsible for rendering the actual budget. I also wanted to include the ability to edit the budget in-line, which functionality is included in this component. However, when I edit the budget, the component is not re-rendering:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import Table from '../../../../node_modules/material-ui/lib/table';
import numeral from 'numeral';
import InlineEdit from 'react-edit-inline';

const TableRow = Table.TableRow;
const TableRowColumn = Table.TableRowColumn;

const displayName = 'Budget';
const propTypes = {
    budget       : PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default class Budget extends Component {
    constructor( props, context ) {
        super(props, context);
        console.log('Budget this:', this.props);
        this.handleBudgetChange = this.handleBudgetChange.bind(this);
    }

    validateBudget( num ) {
        return (Number(num) > 0 && Number(num) < 100 && !Number.isNaN(num));
    }

    handleBudgetChange( num ) {
        const inputNum = Number(num.budget) > 1 ? Number(num.budget) / 100 : Number(num.budget);
        const budgetId = this.props.budget._id;
        this.props.updateBudget(budgetId, inputNum);
    }

    render() {
        const cellStyle = {
            textAlign : 'center'
        };
        const editCellStyle = {
            cursor         : 'pointer',
            textDecoration : 'underline'
        };
        const { department, owner, budget } = this.props.budget;
        const editControl = (
            <InlineEdit
                validate={this.validateBudget}
                change={this.handleBudgetChange}
                text={numeral(this.props.budget.budget).format('0.0%')}
                paramName="budget"
                activeClassName="editing"
            />
        );

        return (
            <TableRow style={cellStyle}
                      displayBorder={false}>
                <TableRowColumn>{department}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn style={editCellStyle}>{editControl}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{owner.name}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn style={editCellStyle}>Edit</TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
        );
    }
}

Budget.displayName = displayName;
Budget.propTypes = propTypes;
```

When I edit the budget in-line, the value changes for the state, but the component isn't re-rendering it.

Should I be connecting the `<Budget />` component to the store and listening for changes here as well?

Or is there a better approach to what I'm trying to do?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I arrived here because I have the same problem (or at least symptom). I was expecting your Budget to connect by itself, however, which is what I'm doing. Your connected component connects to `state.departmentBudgets.budgets`, but I don't see `departmentBudgets` in your state, so it seems like it should conenct to `state.budgets`.

Answer (score 2):

At a quick glance, is it just that you aren't passing the right prop down to your child component? For your DepartmentBudgets in the container, should you be mapping budgets to just 'budgets' and not 'budgets.budgets'?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `this.props.updateBudget(budgetId, inputNum);` is firing its parent component's function correctly? When it gets passed down from the container, you'll want to do something like `<DepartmentBudgets updateBudget={this.budgetDidchange.bind(this)} ... />`. I don't believe the constructor binding makes up for this, but you could always throw a `console.log("test")` in the function to see if the problem is the function itself and nothing to do with Redux.

See: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html